# bash. Grep text file looking for lines from other file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Is it possible to analize text file let's say `log.txt` looking for lines from the other file - let's say `config.txt`. I tried to do following thing:

```
while read -r line;
do
    if grep -q $line $log_path; then 
        echo "Found line: $line" >> $out_log
        break
    else echo "Line not found: $line" >> $out_log
    fi
done < $conf_path
```

`$conf_path` is a path like `/path/to/config.txt`

`$log_path` is a path like `/path/to/log.txt`

and the `$out_log` is the `/path/to/output_log.txt` which is used to test if script works properly.

Example `$line` is `"ERROR: MESSAGE: \[Library not found \!\]"`. I tested grep instruction outside the script and it found that line properly, so I do not think that grep is the problem here. Every time `else` statement is executed.

Thank you, Community, for any suggestions,

Best regards, Max

Comment: So what doesn't work in your current script, what's the error message?

Comment: I do not really know. Seems like my grep condition always returns false thus `else` statement is always called. But I tried to use very similiar grep from hand and it returned found line.

Comment: Please can you provide a minimal reproducible example with some data that causes the script to fail, as upon trying it worked for me: https://pastebin.com/BXBM3T9L

Comment: "break" would imply stop the loop after first successful find.
if replaced by "continue" the loop will read the next line from $conf_path.

Comment: Also, try by replacing with below line

grep -q "${line}" "${log_path}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

**Code:**

```
while read -r line
do if grep -q "${line}" $log_path
then  echo "Found line: $line" >> $out_log
else echo "Line not found: $line" >> $out_log
fi
done < $conf_path
```

**Example:**

```
bash-3.2$ echo $conf_path ; cat $conf_path
config.txt
ERROR: MESSAGE: \[Library not found \!\]
ERROR: MESSAGE: \[File not found \!\]
ERROR: MESSAGE: \[Path not found \!\]
ERROR: MESSAGE: \[Permission denied \!\]
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ echo $log_path; cat $log_path
log.txt
INFO: MESSAGE: Script Starts
INFO: MESSAGE: Some command output
ERROR: MESSAGE: [Library not found !]
INFO: MESSAGE: Some other command output
ERROR: MESSAGE: [Path not found !]
INFO: MESSAGE: Exit script with 2
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ while read -r line; do if grep -q "${line}" $log_path; then  echo "Found line: $line" >> $out_log; else echo "Line not found: $line" >> $out_log; fi; done < $conf_path
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ echo $out_log; cat $out_log
output_log.txt
Found line: ERROR: MESSAGE: \[Library not found \!\]
Line not found: ERROR: MESSAGE: \[File not found \!\]
Found line: ERROR: MESSAGE: \[Path not found \!\]
Line not found: ERROR: MESSAGE: \[Permission denied \!\]
bash-3.2$
```

Hope this helps. Good Luck !!

Comment: `"${line}"` It was the key to proper work. Thank you sir